# im trying to find prime numbers 1-n using for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

Im trying to find prime numbers and it seems i have made mistake but i cannot find it by myself for hours 
here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){

    int n,a,b;
    printf("enter a number=> \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(a=2;a<=n;a++){
        for(b==2;b<=a;b++){
            if(a%b==0){
            break;
            }else{printf("Prime number: %d\n",a);}

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

b suppose to increase but its not increasing, i also assigned b==2 but it prints out b=1

Comment: `b==2` should be `b=2` single equals.

Comment: `b==2` is a boolean construct.  If b is equal to 2, then `b==2` equals `1` (true), but if b is not equal to 2, then `b==2` equals `0`(false).

Comment: First fix "=" mistake then check your program...it'll print "prime number" many many times...

Comment: @Adriano yes it is. and also b isnt look like counter :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
for(b==2;b<=a;b++)  
//    ^ Replace it with assignment operator '='
```

to

```
for(b = 2; b*b <=a; b++)  
//          ^ Reduce the unnecessary loop iteration.
```

Comment: Why b square is less than or equal to a ?

Comment: This alone is not sufficient, still more is required, prime number has exactly two factors, you should consider adding these details plus the sieve technique

Comment: @P0W; Sieve technique!  I still haven't implemented yet :P

Comment: @user3569411; You need to check only up to square root of a number.

Comment: @haccks [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: @P0W; I know but haven't implemented this algo yet.

Answer (score 1):

`b == 2` in your code compares `b` with `2`, evaluates into a `1` if they both have the same value, evaluates into a `0` if they are different.

You rather seem to want to have an assignment there, which is to be done with `b = 2` instead.

After that, you also should consider running the `printf` statement under a more strict circumstance, than every time `a % b` isn't equal to `0`. That more strict circumstance could be, for example, when `b` is finally equal to `a - 1`.

You could do all that with least number of changes by changing your code into the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main( ){

    int n, a, b;
    printf( "enter a number=> \n" );
    scanf( "%d", &n );
    for ( a = 2; a <= n; a++ ){
        for ( b = 2; b <= a; b++ ){ // removed one = sign
            if ( a % b == 0 ){
                break;
            }
            else if ( b == a - 1 ) {    // added the if ( b == a - 1 )
                printf( "Prime number: %d\n", a );
            }

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `=` instead of `==`.